# ClassNotFoundException in a library Project in a maven Project

Tags: maven, tomcat, dependencies, java

In my maven Project in eclipse, I have added a normal Java- Project as a Library project (with  Java- Build Path). This worked fine until I wrote a method in this Library project that makes use of org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils . I added this external library both with an "external jar" in the java buildpath properties of the library project and as a maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

in eclipse both projects show no errors, but when run it gives me an ClassNotFoundException in the library project (btw. if I use the exact same line of code in the source of the maven project, it works just fine)

The maven project runs on a tomcat7-server.

Now my question is: how can I fix this? The Library project is used by other projects as well, so just copying the code into the Maven project would be a less favored solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about the codec library but I know that some of the apache commons libraries have dependencies on classes in other libraries/jars. When it gives the ClassNotFoundException, does it say this about DigestUtils or some other class. If it's some other class, it should likely mean that you will need another class from another jar that DigestUtils depends on.

Comment: It specifically say digestutils.

Answer (score 0):

You need this library (commons-codec) in your WEB-INF/lib folder, not on your build path.

Comment: Shouldn't this happen if i add the maven dependency (in the pom file)?

Comment: No, the maven references are basically similar to having the jars in the build path

Comment: So how would i add ot to this folder then?

Comment: Just simple copy paste